# Meaning of "orienting response"

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of Orienting response in below passage?

What is it about TV that has such a hold on US? In part, the attraction seems to spring from our biological ‘**orienting response**.’ First described by Ivan Pavlov in 1927, the orienting response is our instinctive visual or auditory reaction to any sudden or novel stimulus. It is part of our evolutionary heritage, a builtin sensitivity to movement and potential predatory threats.

Comment: When you come across an unusual phrase, such as this, best google it:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orienting_response

Comment: I saw the source, Can you explain it in simple speech with an example?

Comment: From the internet: example of orienting response? **1. a behavioral response to an altered, novel, or sudden stimulus, such as turning one's head toward an unexpected noise.**  and **In dogs and other animals this includes such signs of attention as pricked-up ears, head turned toward the stimulus, increased muscular tension, and physiological changes detectable with instruments.**

Answer (score 2):

We have a biologically innate tendency to look in the direction from which noise (or smell or touch) come from. You hear a noise on your left, you look to your left.

Answer (score 1):

“Orienting” means pointing this way or that.  (“Orient” means “east”, and before magnetic compasses were available, sunrise — in the east — was used to align buildings, roads, and such.)

The “orienting” response is when you *respond* to a sound or a light by looking in that direction.

Comment: "Orienting" also means understanding where you are. Another related word is "Orienteering" which means to find things using a map and a compass which requires both knowing where you are and where you are going.

Comment: @ohwilleke — “orienting” in that sense is _orienting yourself_, figuring out which way you are currently pointing and which way you are supposed to be pointing.